# How to periodically output the amount of performed actions in loadrunner

Tags: loadrunner

I'm running a script that registers a customer and performs multiple payments to that customer account. Then I create a scenario by Controller, that initializes several users and for each of them the script mentioned above is being run, thus sending payments to different users' accounts. Now, what I want is to obtain the number of total payments performed every minute. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You have a named transaction for payment.  You have a count of payments which occur within a defined window.  You have graph granularity which you can set to 60 seconds so you can observe both the graph and the graph data for each and every minute of your test